# Django admin form field - display objecy-dependent query results in a select box

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms, django-admin

I've a Django form field of type CharField in  a model.
I wish to populate it with items from *a few different* DB tables, **that are dependent on the current model being edited**.

I know I can use `formfield_for_choice_field` or the `widgets` override, **but it doesn't suffice - I don't get the currently edited object (or even its ID)**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
class MyAdminModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta(object):
        model = MyModel

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyAdminModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if not self.instance.pk:
            return # don't fetch related choices for new objects

        current_event = self.instance.event
        self.fields['route'] = ChoiceField(choices=OtherModel.objects.filter(event=current_event).values_list('id', 'title'))


@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    form = MyAdminModelForm
```